# Remove trailing zeros and thousand separator (comma)

Tags: c#

Since I am using this to remove trailing zeros when there is no value behind decimal:

```
decimal.Parse(variable).ToString("G29")
```

But it doesn't give thousand separator. For example:

```
string amount = "54321.00"
string amount2 = "54321.55"
string parsed = decimal.Parse(amount).ToString("G29");
string parsed2 = decimal.Parse(amount2).ToString("G29");
//parsed = 54321
//parsed2 = 54321.55

//my goal
//parsed = 54,321
//parsed2 = 54,321.55
```

Is there any better format type?

Comment: Considering what you want, why on earth are you using `G29` format? Have you even donde a minimal research of the avaliable standard numeric format strings and what each one does? You can start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: And what should the formatted output of `54321.556` be? `54,321.556`? Or `54,321.56`?

Comment: @InBetween when there is no value behind decimal (.000), it will be hidden. Output of `54321.556` should be `54,321.556`.

Comment: Ok, then read the provided link and do some research. If none apply (still a good read) then maybe reading on custom numeric format strings might be a good idea.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as text to begin with? Store them as double or decimal depending on their meaning.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen My guess is that he has unformatted numeric strings and he wants to format them to some custom format.

Answer (score 4):

**Use a custom format**

```
string format = "#,#.##";

decimal noDecimalPlaces = 54321.00m;
decimal decimalPlaces = 54321.55m;

Console.WriteLine(noDecimalPlaces.ToString(format)); // writes 54,321
Console.WriteLine(decimalPlaces.ToString(format)); // writes 54,321.55
```

You can read more about formatting decimals [on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx).

**The way this works**

The latter part `.##` specifies that you allow up to two decimal places. The former part `#,#` specifies that you want to separate the integer part of your value.

**Note**:

The number formatting is still *culture specific*, so for cultures that use `,` as the decimal separator and `.` for digit grouping your numbers will be displayed as `54.321` and `54.321,55` instead. You can find out more about formatting in .NET [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types).

Comment: The note is the actual added value of this answer. Its the `UICulture` which determines the format of the separator.